# Repetir Bloco com animação - CSS - PHP

Tags: php, css, css3

Tenho uma animação em meu site, e preciso duplicar ela, ou seja, preciso criar mais de um "quadrado" com a animação, sem que ela conflita com outra:

[SITE](http://www.planow.com.br/nobre/servicos.php)

de uma olhada la em baixo, e clique em " veja mais informações"

**CODIGO**

```
      <section class="conteudo1">
          <div class="servicos-3 coluna imagem-fade"  style="background:url(img/img-servicos.png) no-repeat;"></div>
          <div class="servicos-9 coluna conteudo-fade">
            <div class="titulo-conteudo-fade">
              <h2>ORGANIZAÇÃO FINANCEIRA PARA EVENTOS</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="texto-conteudo-fade">
              <span>Confira nossa variedade de serviços financeiros que podem ser realizados no seu evento.</span>
              <br/><br/><br/>
              <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle"><button class="btn btn-default btn-servicos">ver mais serviços</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section class="conteudo2">
          <div id="tabs">
            <div class="x-sair">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle"><img src="img/x-sair-servicos.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 coluna imagem-fade"  style="padding: 30px;background:#ffeed6;">
              <div class="servicos-categoria">
                <div class="btn-group-vertical btns-categoria">
                  <ul class="categoria-list">
                   //CONTEUDO
                  </ul>
                  <div class="botoes">
                    <div class="up"><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;"></a></div>
                    <div class="down"><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;"></a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 coluna conteudo-categoria">
              <div class="titulo-conteudo-fade">
                   //CONTEUDO
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
```

***JS***

```
   jQuery(function($){
  $('section').on('click','button',function(e){
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
jQuery(function($){
  $('section').on('click','img',function(e){
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

Não há problemas no JS, a animação é o flip, preciso apenas ter mais de um "bloco", cada bloco tem 2 seções, a seção "conteudo1" é a parte da frente, a seção "conteudo2" é a seção que ta atrás, na hora que clico em "veja mais info" o efeito do flip acontece e mostra o conteúdo da seção "conteudo2". Tudo está normal, o que eu preciso é apenas criar mais "blocos" como este.... entenderam?

*** SOLUÇÃO ***

a solução era simples, a query tava sendo a mesma, diabos a quatro o pq disso, mas funfou legal :)

Comment: Coloque aqui somente o código que interessa ou está dando erro, ao invés de postar links externos, isso iria ajudar muito.

Comment: @furlan poste o código aqui, Não fique colocando somente os links!

Comment: Coloque aqui *SOMENTE* o código da animação que pretende duplicar, e que animação é essa? Qual o problema no JS?

Comment: @JorgeB. alterei a pergunta, de uma olhada

Comment: Queres ter 2 flips na mesma página certo?

Comment: @JorgeB. alterei a questao, olha a imagem

Comment: O que acontece quando pões como na imagem? Com 2 ou mais blocos?

Comment: as divs ficam coladas, e o efeito acontece nos 2 @JorgeB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor mesmo é dares um `id` no HTML a cada `section`, e cada `card` e usares assim:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="card1" class="card">
    <section id="section1" class="conteudo1">
```

**JQuery:**

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#section1').on('click','img',function(e){
    $('#card1').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

E assim podes garantir que uns não influenciam os outros.

Comment: vo tenta aki e volto a dizer se deu certo.

Comment: nada cara :( .. ta foda

Comment: Põe o exemplo no http://jsfiddle.net/ que fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Experimenta a outra resposta primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('button.btn-servicos').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('div.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
jQuery(function($){
  $('.x-sair img').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('div.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

Tente isso pois recomendo não ficar utilzando vários ids para definir estilos idênticos. Assim fica mais dinâmico e prático no momente em que quizer fazer uma alteração.

Vou explicar o primeiro:

Quando o usuário clicar no no botão com a classe btn-servicos, a função closest() será chamada, partidando do botão clicado, retornando o elemento parent com a classe card mais próximo e assim, inserindo ou removendo a classe flipped dele. O segundo é semelhante.
Basicamente é isso.

@edit

Poderia fazer em uma única função também, adicionando mais de um seletor separados por vírgula:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.x-sair img,button.btn-servicos').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('div.card').toggleClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema dele.

Comment: @Lucas com esse JS, nao acontece o effeito

Comment: Testei em sua página online e funcionou, não 100% como gostaria(todos os cards estavam girando, provavelmente pela duplicação que fiz). Se puder colocar no jsfiddle vai ajudar bastante. Assim pode-se ir modificando e testando num ambiente mais prático e dinámico.